# Xamarin Forms Application - Error ITMS-90171 Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, cocoapods, objective-sharpie

I am trying to create a release build of a Xamarin Forms application but I am running into an error when uploading to the App Store - ITMS-90171: "invalid Build Structure".

The full error is:

ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'x.app/Frameworks/GBPing.framework/GBPing.a' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

I used Sharpie and CocoaPods to create the GBPing framework and then I followed the Binding Objective-C Libraries guide to create the binding project.

The application works and I can run it on the device successfully but I just can't get the release build to upload to the App Store.

From Googling around it seems like in Xcode there is a way to stop this file from being copied into the binary but I haven't been able to figure out how to do something similar in Xamarin.

I have tried the obvious things like cleaning and rebuilding the application with no success.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated,

Adam.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this issue.

It turns out that the folder containing my binding had the `GBPing.a` file present. I deleted this file and then also the `bin` and `obj` folders from inside the iOS project folder. Finally, I Selected `Build -> Clean All` and then rebuilt the application.

Hopefully this will help someone else down the line!